# Closing mysqli connection produces: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I close my connection I get this error:

PHP Warning: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

AND this error:

PHP Warning: Property access is not allowed yet

I have made sure to close the connection outside the loop but wherever I place the breakpoint the error's line number changes.

I have my php code here:

```
$sql = "SELECT arrivalDate, departDate FROM holidayletdatabase.bookings 
WHERE departDate > '$current_date'";
if ($result = $connect->query($sql)) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($bookings, $obj);
    }
    $result->close();
}
$connect->close(); //closes the connection
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Add `mysqli_error($connect)` to the query and enable error reporting.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have added this and it now displays these errors on the PHP webpage and has added more information about the connection in the debug console when inspecting the variable $connect

Answer (score 0):

Try to define $result first before using it in the if statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT arrivalDate, departDate FROM holidayletdatabase.bookings 
WHERE departDate > '$current_date'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($bookings, $obj);
    }
    $result->close();
}
$connect->close(); //closes the connection
```